# Hidden Network?

Tags: network, wifi

I live in the country, no neighbors, never another wifi signal and now one appears. Does someone please have the reason why?

I'm extremely creeped out thinking someone planted spyware. If so, how do I find or disable it?

Comment: spyware is something that gets installed, it's not a new network

Comment: Is this additional Wifi on, if your computer is turned off? How did you find out, with which device can you see the second net (computer/smartphone)?

Comment: I got the app and my wifi and my cell comes up.

Comment: Yes it's additional that has never appeared. I wish I could put a picture on my comment

Comment: @Nikki - You should try to answer the questions precisely, they are asked on purpose. As it is, people have to guess about your situation and therefore cannot give you good advice.

Comment: You don't need to add a picture, just type the text, that's probably enough info.

Comment: New tv lately? Some tv's give out a wifi signal. Also entertainment systems and other devices that can connect to the internet can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wifi scanner like vistumbler. So you can find out if there is a hotspot.

Comment: @Nikki what spitz means is that you can get an app for your phone that can  show you the direction of a wifi access point - you just walk around looking for the possible new hardware

Answer (score 4):

There are apps for your phone that can show you the direction of a wifi signal. With this, you can walk around to pinpoint the direction of a wifi access point.

I have used tools like that to look for rogue access points in companies (as well as competing wifi APs that are interfering with signals).

Answer (score 3):

What device are you using? How many devices are you using? Have you tried turning each off, and then seeing if one of the devices you own is generating it's own network?

Most mobile phones allow for users to create "hotspots", an access point for other devices over WiFi. It's not unheard of for novice smartphone users to enable them by accident.

Comment: I think you jumped to conclusions too soon: http://superuser.com/a/1094678/128626

Comment: @schroeder Unhelpful questions get unhelpful answers. There is an absolute lack of information by the question poster to allow people to answer the question. There is absolutely no investigation by the user themselves (or at least written) which shows no initiative. That's why I proposed 3 questions.

Comment: That's why it's better to ask the questions first and get a sense of the possible, then formulate an answer. It takes more work in the end, but the quality of answers improves. Help them help you get to a good place.

Comment: @Nikki, have you bought any new devices that may present some sort of hotspot? Any Internet enabled cameras, fridges, a tablet, a car?

Answer (score 2):

More and more devices are actually coming equipped with WiFi and can serve as a WiFi hotspot or router. You are probably detecting one of these devices.

Since you say you live in the country and have no neighbors, it is most likely a mobile based WiFi hotspot.

Some examples include:

- Mobile internet hotspot devices that allow other devices to connect to them via WiFi.
- Some mobile phones can share their internet connection by becoming a WiFi hotspot.
- Some vehicles are actually internet enabled, and can also act as a WiFi hotspot.

If any of these devices are anywhere near your home, you might detect the signal.

If it is not a mobile hotspot then it would have to be a fixed installation somewhere, such as a home, or a building. Perhaps a neighbor is boosting their signal so they can use it anywhere on their property, and they are boosting it enough for you to detect.

As far as what to do about it, if there is a public roadway nearby, or you happen to be detecting a boosted signal from a neighbor, then there is nothing you can or should do about it. It's just another internet enabled device out there.

Now, if you live on a huge ranch and there is no way a signal can get that close without being on your property, then you probably have someone trespassing, and might want to look around and see who it is and why they are on your property.

But unless you have a Texas sized ranch, this is probably not the case, and you are detecting WiFi from a public road or a neighbor.

One other possibility is you purchased a device that can serve as a WiFi hotspot and didn't realize it, and you are actually seeing that signal.

In all cases, except for the trespasser, these signals are harmless.

Using an app on your phone that detects WiFi strength may help you track down where the signal is coming from, although if the source is mobile, it may be harder to track down.